# How to add thumbnail and mouse hover to images in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have gridview, in that values are populated from the `images` table with columns `ID, Images`. When all images are retrieved from database, I have to see thumbnail view particular image with big size while moving cursor over the image.

Here is my gridview

```
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" />
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images" >
      <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("images") %>'/>
      </EditItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: This should be helpful: http://www.dotnetcode.in/2011/07/how-to-show-large-image-on-mouseover.html

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Comment: ACTUALLY, I need thumbnail inside the gridview. when I move cursor over the image it should show in big size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the Image inside  rather than  for test. Add an image source to the image control,also add css class:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("images") %>' CssClass="myimage" src="Image/normal.jpg"/>
```

I would rename mouseover images to normalimagename + over, i.e. normalover.jpg". Now I would add the jquery script block to the head of my page, just under my jquery include script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("img.myimage").hover(function () {
                var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.jpg";
                $(this).attr("src", src);
            },
function () {
    var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over", "");
    $(this).attr("src", src);
});
        });
</script>
```

It will work with .jpg only. change the .jpg in "over.jpg" to any other filetype you want it to work.

Comment: nice explanation,which I expected.